# How to display div from a.php file using iframe?

Tags: php, iframe

How to display div #b(only) from a.php file using iframe?

a.php

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="a">
            Nice day!
        </div>

        <div id="b">
            Nice night!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

b.php

```
<IFRAME width=1200" height="1500" scrolling=no frameborder=0 src="a.php"; marginWidth=0 marginHeight=0></IFRAME>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're looking to do.. are you looking for the div to contain the iframe, or what?

Comment: it displays the whole contents of file a.php. I would like to display only #div id="b"

Answer (score 1):

What is the goal here? Will a.php display different comment based on how it is called?

One option is to add a parameter Id:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 'a') {
  //display div#a
} else {
  //display div#b
}

<iframe src="a.php?id=b" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this.

```
<IFRAME width=1200" height="1500" scrolling=no frameborder=0 src="/a.php#divid"; marginWidth=0 marginHeight=0></IFRAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery:

```
$('#target').load('a.html #b'); // take #b from a.html and put in #target
```